# Доступ к Spinner из адаптера

Tags: android

Адаптер вынесен в отдельный класс. Пытаюсь получить доступ из него к Spinner, который находится в MainActivity таким образом, но пишет что в адаптере ссылается на пустой объект.

В адаптере написал так

```
private Spinner spinner;

    public void setSpinner(Spinner spinner) {
        this.spinner = spinner;
    }
```

А в MainActivity

```
private Spinner spinner;
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

arrayAdapter = new WordsAdapter(MainActivity.this, rusArr);
arrayAdapter.setSpinner(spinner);
```

Comment: вообще адаптер не должен управлять виджетами активити. Какую задачу вам на самом деле нужно решить?

Comment: Мне нужно в классе-адаптере проверять выбранное значение из spinner

Comment: это понятно и из вопроса, опишите сам алгоритм того, что вы хотите получить в итоге. уверен, эта задача решается по другому

Comment: В общем приложение (Русско-Англ словарь) сейчас делает следующее: Есть БД с 2 таблицами. rusen и enrus. В главном MainActivity есть спиннер где два значения русско-английский и англо-русский. Слова выводятся в зависимости от того какое значение выбрано в ListView. Но я сейчас сделал кастомный адаптер для listview где кроме textview есть еще и imagebutton. Так вот в этом адаптере есть метод позволяющий при клике на ImageButton добавить слово в избранное. Соответственно мне бы хотелось проверять значение spinner для того чтобы знать в какой таблице производить обновление данных.

Comment: Просто завидите в активити переменную, которая будет указывать, что выбрано в спиннере (например типа int: 1 - англо-русский, 2 - русско-английский), затем передавайте  через конструктор адаптера эту переменную в сам адаптер и по ее значению выбирайте какую использовать таблицу.

Comment: через intent передавать или как?

Comment: через конструктор адаптера, добавьте в конструктор еще один аргумент

Comment: Получилось. Спасибо

Comment: Также передал в конструктор переменную типа SQLiteDatabase. Можно ли так делать?